# Make Contact form 7 radio button large with a big gap between label and button?

Tags: css, contact-form-7

I am working on various contact form 7 controls.

The one that I am having issues with so far is making a radio button bigger, changing the background color and adding a huge gap between the label and the button.

I have looked on the suggested popups here including the subject Make radio button bigger but none seems to make any difference.

Here is a screenshot that contains two images, top image is the out I am getting from my version.

The image below is my preferred version.

Here is what I have tried so far.

I made an ID code of customized-radio in the ID attribute of the radio button control I am using.

On my form, I added the id attribute:

```
[radio rehireable id:customized-radio label_first "Yes"]
```

Then custom CSS:

```
#cuustomized-radio {
  background-color:#f1f1f1 !important;
  gap: 3.3em; /* space between label and button */
  appearance: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  color: currentColor;
  width: 1.15em;
  height: 1.15em;
  border: 0.15em solid currentColor;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Any ideas what I could do differently to make this work?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this simple CSS code will work for you

```css
#cuustomized-radio {
  background-color:#f1f1f1 !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  font: inherit;
  color: currentColor;
  width: 1.15em;
  height: 1.15em;
  border: 0.15em solid currentColor;
  float:right;
  margin:5px;
}
.divdiv {
  width:50%;
  margin-top:10px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  border:1px dashed #000;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size:18px;
}

body {
padding:5%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>

<h4>SUBJECT TO REHIRE? <span style="color:red;">*</span></h4>
<div class="divdiv">
<label> Yes </label>
<input id="cuustomized-radio" type="radio" name="test">
</div>
<div class="divdiv">
<label> No </label>
<input id="cuustomized-radio" type="radio" name="test">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: My apologies for the late response. I have tried it but it did not change anything.

Thanks a lot for your efforts though.

Maybe it is contact form 7 issue, I don't know.